# "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions

Tags: c#, json, api

Полностью ошибка звучит так:
**"Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл."**

Я написал небольшое приложение, хотел поиграться с API

Вот что у меня есть:

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebServer.Model
{
    public class Car
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public string Brend { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WebServer.Model
{
    public class CarsResponse
    {
        public CarsResponse(Car car)
        {
            this.Id = car.Id;
            this.Mark = car.Mark;
            this.Brend = car.Brend;
            this.Year = car.Year;
        }

        public CarsResponse()
        {

        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public string Brend { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WebServer.Model
{
    public class AppData : DbContext
    {
        public AppData() : base("DBConnection") { }

        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace WebServer.Model
{
    public static class AppContextObj
    {
        public static AppData db = new AppData();
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь прописать запрос

```
static void Main()
        {
            HttpListener server = new HttpListener();
            server.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:31034/");
            server.Start();
            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions { Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All) };
            while (server.IsListening)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
                if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (context.Request.RawUrl == "/api/cars/")
                        {
                            var carList = AppContextObj.db.Cars.ToList(); 
                            string response = JsonSerializer.Serialize(AppContextObj.db.Cars.ToList().ConvertAll(c => new CarsResponse(c)), options);
                            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
                            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
                            using (Stream stream = context.Response.OutputStream)
                            {
                                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                            }
                        }
                        else throw new Exception();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                        context.Response.Close();
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

Установленные пакеты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот ошибка при дебаге

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте сначала достучаться к api с помощью стороннего приложения (chrome, postman). Есть ощущение, что проблема именно там.

Comment: @RustamAliev, проблему решил. Вопрос был в версии .NET Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в версии .net framework, в текущем проекте был использован .net framework 4.6.2, обновил до 4.8 и всё работает как надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]